# flask login getting logged out in pc but logged in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, backend, flask-login

I am making a streaming website with flask as the background and using flask login to maintain the login system. So everything is going well and fine but whenever i change anthing in the html the user is getting logged out in pc but staying logged in mobile .

any possible reasons for this and the solution

Comment: How do you store the login-information? And how do you verify that the user is "logged out"?

Comment: I use it simple as a session and not store it and logout the the user using the method logout_user() on a logout route which is set as @login_required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.